Creating a global alias for a SQL Server Instance
Forgive me if this is an easy question, but I have tried finding an answer but I really don't know what to search (I'm a software dev, with only some limited DBA experience).
We have test SQL servers setup with 3 instances each:
TSTSQL01\Enterprise
TSTSQL01\Warehouse
TSTSQL01\Legacy

TSTSQL02\Enterprise
TSTSQL02\Warehouse
TSTSQL02\Legacy

TSTSQL03\Enterprise
...

In production we don't use instances, we have 3 separate servers:
PRDSQL01 --"Enterprise" server
PRDSQL02 --"Warehouse" server
PRDSQL03 --"Legacy" server

Due to limitations of our legacy COBOL application, I am in need of a connection string that has EXACTLY 8 characters to match the length of the production connection strings. What I am wanting to do is create an alias for each test sql server that allows this, using the tstsql01 example above would ideally look like:
TSQL1ENT --maps to TSTSQL01\Enterprise
TSQL1WAR --maps to TSTSQL01\Warehouse
TSQL1LEG --maps to TSTSQL01\Legacy

My current workaround is to use the SQL Configuration Manager to add an alias. This lets me connect to the database on that server, but not on local workstations. Our legacy COBOL app runs 75% of the code from the server, so it works for that. But the remaining 25% of the code runs locally on their workstations. That means I have to add that alias on every single tester's machine (I've scripted it out via powershell, but testers aren't admins so it requires a help desk request for every single person for every single test server).
Thanks in advance for the help!

There is no such thing as a global alias, aliases are artifacts of the drivers and as you've found out are local to the profile.
The proper way of handling this (other than not tripling up instances) is:

Add 2 additional IP addresses for a total of 3 unique per machine (1 for each instance).
Configure each instance to only use one IP address and only listen on that one.
Configure each instance to listen on TCP Port 1433.
Add DNS A/AAAA records for the 8 character name you want and put in that instance's IP.


That makes perfect sense, thank you for the quick response!

Another option is to make a single DNS alias, of say three letters, then get each instance to listen on different ports. Then your connection string can use
Sql,1433
Sql,1437
Sql,1438

